# Change distro, keep software AND ppas

Tags: distributions

Continuation of [my other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242537/change-distro-keeps-software). Besides the software, can I save the PPAs in a file?

Comment: What do you mean by “save the PPAs in a file”? Aren't they already saved in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`? What else do you need?

Comment: Apparently nothing, I did not know where/how they were stored